# How to create and print the contents of a class?

Tags: python, class, object, printing

I am creating a class structure in python for a city, that stores the name, country, population and language for a city, all of which are input by the user. The information shall then be printed.

I think that I may be successful in storing the information within the class structure (although this may be wrong as well), but I am unsuccessful in printing the information. Currently, I am receiving the error that `int object is not subscriptable`.

```
class User():
    def _init_(self, username, password, email, numOfLogins):
        User.username = username
        User.password = password
        User.email = email
        User.numOfLogins = numOfLogins

#User Record Array Creation
def createUserArray(num , User):
    UserArray = []
    for x in range(num):
        UserArray.append(User)
    return UserArray

#User Record Array Population
def populateUserArray(num, UserArray):
    for x in range(len(userArray)):
        UserArray[x].username = str(input("Enter username."))
        UserArray[x].password = str(input("Enter password."))
        UserArray[x].email = str(input("Enter email address."))
        UserArray[x].numOfLogins = int(input("Enter number of logins."))
    return UserArray

#User Record Array Display
def displayUserArray(UserArray, num):
    for x in range(len(userArray)):
        print(UserArray[x].username, UserArray[x].password, UserArray[x].email, str(UserArray[x].numOfLogins))

#Top Level Program
numOfUsers = 3
userArray = createUserArray(numOfUsers, User)
userArray = populateUserArray(numOfUsers, userArray)
displayUserArray(numOfUsers, userArray)
```

The contents of the class should all be displayed at the end of the program, but at the minute my program crashes due to the error - `int object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: Traceback seems to be `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/Python/HorizontalTesting/test.py", line 33, in <module>
    display_user_array(numOfUsers, userArray)
  File "D:/Projects/Python/HorizontalTesting/test.py", line 27, in display_user_array
    print(user_array[x].username, user_array[x].password, user_array[x].email, str(user_array[x].numOfLogins))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0):

you can always implement the method : `__str__(self)` of an object , and then when you just print it with :

```
your_obj = User(...)
print your_obj
```

your `__str__(self)` will be called and you can return from it whatever you want to print.
for example:

```
def __self__(self):
    return `this class has the following attributes: %s %s %s %s` % (self.username,self.password,self.email ,self.numOfLogins )
```

and this what will get print, i think it is more efficient and well coded to work like that and not creating a function that print each class attribute separately.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your error is quite simple and obvious: you defined the function as `displayUserArray(UserArray, num)` but call it with `displayUserArray(numOfUsers, userArray)` - IOW you pass the arguments in the wrong order.

This being said, almost all your code is wrong, you obviously don't get the difference between a class and instance and how to use a class to create instances. I strongly suggest you read *at least* [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects), and check a couple other tutorial and/or example code on the topic of classes and instances.